# How to fetch id from console log firestore and react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

fam, I have a document added to cloud firestore, I can successfully read data from the database, I want to get only the ID from the document, here's the code snippet:-

```js
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [fetch, setFetch] = useState({
    id: "",
  });

  const {userId} = useParams();
  
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "microsystems/" + userId , "reportmcs")

  useEffect(()=>{ 
    const getTasks = async () => {
      const q = query(collectionRef)
      await getDocs(q).then((task)=>{
       let tasksData = task.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id}))
      setTasks(tasksData)
      setFetch(tasksData)
      console.log("fetchData", tasksData)
      console.log("taskData", tasksData)
      }).catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err)
      })
    }
    getTasks()
  }, [])

  let sampleId = fetch.id
    console.log("currentvalue from doc", sampleId)
```

What I tried to do was that in the code snippet above, I have two states above, the second state, that is (fetch), I'm currently using that to get the id for that particular document, I can see all the fields in the document in my console log but when I try to get only the id, it returns undefined..

Here's my console log:-
[image]

How can I target only that id and view in my console log???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query returns only 1 document then you can just read first item in that array as shown below or alternatively maps a new array of IDs if there are many documents. Try:

```
const getTasks = async () => {
    const q = query(collectionRef)

    const snapshot = await getDocs(q)
    const tasksData = task.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id
    }))
    
    console.log(tasksData[0].id)
  
    // in case of multiple documents
    console.log(tasksData.map(task => task.id))

    setTasks(tasksData)
    setFetch(tasksData)
    console.log("fetchData", tasksData)
    console.log("taskData", tasksData)
}
```

Comment: how then do I use this with a state, like for instance in my code snippet, I set a state to fetch the id, that is, let sampleId = fetch.id

Comment: @Deezy try setting that in a state? `const [sampleId, setSampleId] = useState("");` then use `setSampleId(tasksData[0].id)` to update the value.